# Unable to connect to MockServer from Django Docker container

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, mockserver

I've setup a Django container along with a MockServer container running in docker-compose. I can access the MockServers' endpoints fine using postman, but when doing a request from the python container I get an error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=1080): Max retries exceeded with url: /devices (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6d83e4fa60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Here is my MockServer.properties:

```
mockserver.maxSocketTimeout=120000
mockserver.dynamicallyCreateCertificateAuthorityCertificate=true
mockserver.directoryToSaveDynamicSSLCertificate=.
mockserver.sslCertificateDomainName=localhost
mockserver.sslSubjectAlternativeNameDomains=www.example.com,www.another.com
mockserver.sslSubjectAlternativeNameIps=127.0.0.1


mockserver.enableCORSForAPI=true
mockserver.enableCORSForAllResponses=true
mockserver.corsAllowHeaders=Cache-Control, Postman-Token, Host, User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Connection, Allow, Content-Encoding, Content-Length, Content-Type, ETag, Expires, Last-Modified, Location, Server, Vary, Authorization
mockserver.corsAllowMethods=CONNECT, DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, PATCH, TRACE
mockserver.corsAllowCredentials=true
```

My code for doing the request looks like this:

```
return requests.get(
        URL + 'devices',
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth.decode('utf-8')}
    )
```

MockServer url is http://localhost:1080, and it works when using any other external url.

ANy idea what can cause this?

Comment: Could it be that the url is redirecting to itself rather than going to the host machine?

Comment: you need use your MockServer ipaddress instead, you can look it up using `ifconfig`

Comment: @minglyu thank you! This solved the problem!